# Redefined maketitle gives error

Tags: titles, document-classes

I'm currently using a template I found online, it included a `.cls` file that modified the usual `\maketitle`. Every time I compile with this class I get an error after the `\maketitle`saying `There's no line to end`, here is the whole `.cls` I'm using:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Conference proceedings and article templates for
% personal open-archiving activities
% September 2012
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS USEFUL PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
                right=2cm,%
                                top=2.25cm,%
                                bottom=2.25cm,%
                                headheight=11pt,%
                                letterpaper]{geometry}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES AND TABLES CAPTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,small},%
                labelsep=period,%
                justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE HEADER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION/SUBSECTION/PARAGRAPH SET-UP
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
```

and here is a minimal example that produces the error:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} 
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} 


\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} 
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} 


\PaperTitle{Title} % Article title

\Authors{Julio Cáceres\textsuperscript{1}*} 
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{stuff}} 
\affiliation{*\textbf{Email}: e@mail.com} 


\Keywords{key1 -- key2 -- key3} 
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords} 

\begin{document}
\flushbottom    

\maketitle

Hi there

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We will need more code. Please give us a compilable but minimal document which lets us play around with your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the whole file? there is no redefinition of `\maketitle` and the command `\PaperTitle` is never defined. Have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: is the class `SelfArx` something other people should know about?  i see nothing in your simple mwe, so i guess the problem is in your class file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the class file provided was not complete, this solution found it here [SelfArx](https://github.com/Albex/Advanced_Architecture/blob/master/doc/report/SelfArx.cls)

It seems that what you meant by `redefined maketitle giving errors` is to remove the \JournalInfo \Archive and \Abstract, all requiring one arguments, but you did not mark out those corresponding definitions in the `\@maketitle` definition. Thus, when `\maketile` is issued, it expects those inputs. Since those were not supplied by user, it complains `there is no line to end`. To work around is (1) either provide those inputs (2) use \JournalInfo{~} \Archive{~} and \Abstract{~} to cheat or (3) mark out those input as shown below

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
%{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\
%\@Archive\par
%}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-3.5\fboxsep-3.5\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty
%\sffamily\small\textbf{\abstractname}\\
%\@Abstract
\else
%\sffamily\small\textbf{\abstractname}\\
%\@Abstract\\[5pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\
\@Keywords%
\fi
}%
}%
```

results in

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} 
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} 
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.75pt} 


\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} 
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} 


\PaperTitle{Title} % Article title

\Authors{Julio Cáceres\textsuperscript{1}*} 
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{stuff}} 
\affiliation{*\textbf{Email}: e@mail.com} 



\Keywords{key1 -- key2 -- key3} 
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords} 


\begin{document}
\flushbottom   

\maketitle

Hi there
\clearpage
Hi there again
\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```